# Converting an Associative Array to a Table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to convert an Associative Array in the form of an HTML Table. This is how the Array looks like

```
Array ( [] => Harvest_Project Object ( 
               [_root:protected] => project 
               [_tasks:protected] => Array ( ) 
               [_convert:protected] => 1 
               [_values:protected] => Array ( 
                     [id] => \ 
                     [client-id] => - 
                     [name] => Internal 
                     [code] => 
                     [active] => false 
                     [billable] => true 
                     [bill-by] => none 
                     [hourly-rate]=>-
```

And this is the code which I have written in PHP for converting the array to a table

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/HarvestAPI.php');

/* Register Auto Loader */
spl_autoload_register(array('HarvestAPI', 'autoload'));

$api = new HarvestAPI();
$api->setUser( $user );
$api->setPassword( $password );
$api->setAccount( $account );

$api->setRetryMode( HarvestAPI::RETRY );
$api->setSSL(true);

$result = $api->getProjects();
$data = $result->get( "data" );
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><td>Project Name</td>
    <td>Hourly Rate</td>
    </tr>";
        foreach($data as $key=>$fruit) {
                        ?>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit["Name"];?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit["hourly-rate"];?></td></tr>
        <?php ;}
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I would like to display a table with 2 columns-
Project Name and Hourly Rate

But once I execute the code it throws an error 
**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Harvest_Project as array on line 24**. It is referring to this line

```
<tr><td><?php echo $fruit["Name"];?></td>
```

Kindly suggest how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access objects and arrays the same way. Use the `->` operator instead:

```
 <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->name;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $fruit->{'hourly-rate'};?></td></tr>
```

You will need to use the braces around hourly-rate because variables can't have dashes in the name. They're treated as subtraction operators instead.

Answer (score 0):

`$fruit` is an object which contain many keys. To get the `name` key of the `_values` key of the object, you can do like this in your foreach loop :

```
$values = $fruit-> _values
$values['name']; // retrieve the name "Internal"
```

Comment: I don't think he can access an object like you mentioned..$fruit["name"]

Comment: I was totally wrong but I edited my answer, I think it's more correct